# How to set password-less ssh login for multiple remote severs?

Tags: ssh, password, authentication

Machin A is my local pc.
Machine B is my remote vps pc,its ip is vps_ip1.
Machine C is another remote vps pc,its ip is vps_ip2.
To set ssh auto login (without password) as below.

**Step 1: Create Authentication SSH-Kegen Keys on machine A**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa  -P ''
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):    #it is a comment ,input nothing just enter
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

**Step2 Upload Generated Public Keys to machine B**

```
scp  /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@vps_ip1:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Step3 Set Permissions on machine B**

```
ssh root@vps_ip1 "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Now i can login into machine B with ssh command.

```
ssh  root@vps_ip1
```

Almost same steps for machin C.

**Step 1: Create Authentication SSH-Kegen Keys on machine A**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa  -P ''
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):/root/.ssh/myvps
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/myvps.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/myvps.pub.
```

**Step2 Upload Generated Public Keys to machine C**

```
scp  /root/.ssh/myvps.pub root@vps_ip2:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Step3 Set Permissions on machine C**

```
ssh root@vps_ip2 "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Now i can't login into machine C with ssh command.

```
ssh  root@vps_ip2
```

The only difference between them is in step1,**Enter file in which to save the key**,does it matter?
Why my public key can't be saved as /root/.ssh/myvps.pub?
In my case , machine A has to ssh two remote servers,so i must assign other remote server as different name.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why my public key can't be saved as /root/.ssh/myvps.pub?

Your keys can be saved with any name you'd like.  However, the `ssh` client will only *automatically* search for a few standard names, `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, `id_ecdsa`, or `id_ed25519`.  If you want to save it under any other name, you need to specify the file name either on the command line:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/myvps root@vps_ip2
```

or in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host vps_ip2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myvps
    User root
```